# ssrs parameter values case sensitive

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, parameter-passing, case-insensitive

I have a link to a report (SSRS 2008 R2):

```
http://reportserver/pages/reportviewer.aspx?/folder1/report1&hostname=SERVER2
```

This report has a (drop-down list) parameter which contains hostnames.
The drop-down list has these entries:

- server1
- server2
- server3

Problem is that *sometimes* the hostname is passed in uppercase (i.e. SERVER2) and thus the hostname is not selected in the drop-down list does not match the URL parameter. This is because SSRS is case-sensitive with regards to parameter passing.

I do not want the case-sensitivity.

I tried the setting on the Dataset (Dataset Properties - Options - Case sensitivity), but
that did not work.

Is it possible ?

The values in the drop-down box or the URL, I cannot modify.
Best solution would be case-insensitive parameter VALUE passing.

Comment: Where is the source query for the report. You can convert both hostname and QWERTY to the same case in your source query. see example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180055(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: It is NOT about the report query...
This question is about the parameters (drop-down list).

Comment: I know its about parameters. But aren't those parameters (drop-down list) values eventually passed to the source query? My thinking was that you can accept your parameters in either upper case or lower case and then do the conversation to whatever case you wish in the data source query.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `LOWER()` function in your SQL or the `LCASE()` function in SSRS. This function converts the string to all lowercase and if you do it to both sides then effectively case doesn't matter.

So either:

```
WHERE LOWER(fieldName) = LOWER(@parameter)
```

or

```
=LCASE(Fields!fieldName.Value) = LCASE(Parameters!selection.Value)
```

More info:

- [LOWER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174400.aspx)
- [Useful Built-in functions of SSRS](http://bisqlserver2005.blogspot.com.au/2008/06/useful-built-in-functions-of-ssrs.html)

### Update

I slightly misunderstood your question. So you're accessing the report by manually generating the URL with the parameter value in it? This value needs to be passed in a consistent manner or this isn't going to work. SSRS is case sensitive and you can ensure that the available values in the report parameter are formatted consistently using the functions above.

But the generated URL also needs to be consistent. By doing it this way you are explicitly setting the value of the parameter and if it isn't a valid, available value it isn't going to work. The issue here isn't really SSRS it is the fact that the source of the URL does not generate the parameter value in a consistent way.

Fix your URL construction.

Comment: again...this has nothing to do with SQL.
I am reasonably knowledgeable on SQL...this is more of a SSRS issue

Comment: I wouldn't call this an issue with SSRS. You're explicitly setting the the parameter to something that isn't a valid, available value. The construction of the URL needs to be done consistently. Updated the answer.

Comment: haha...the issue is case-sensitivity
I would like that SSRS treats SERVER1 the same as server1

Comment: SSRS is case-sensitive and you cannot change that. At least not the way you're doing things. You need to fix whatever is generating the URL.